# Vmware Fusion Slow Network Performance

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware-fusion

I'm experiencing horrible network performance with VMware Fusion 11.5.1 with a Linux guest (elementary OS 5.1, so essentially Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS).

It seems to just be the network connection that is slow, all other aspects are pretty snappy.

- Loading a webpage spins indefinitely
- pinging a host just sits there

  ```
  avojak@avojak-eos:~$ ping google.com
  PING google.com(den16s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400f:805::200e)) 56 data bytes
  ```
- A `traceroute -I google.com` completes very quickly, which I wouldn't have expected given everything else that I'm seeing...

I'm using a bridged network adapter as recommended:

[image]

I've also [disabled TSO and GSO](https://pleasantsolutions.com/blog/vmware-networking-speed-issue), but that didn't seem to have any effect either. (The is the method used to disable it permanently: https://askubuntu.com/a/1175335)

At this point I can't seem to find anything else to try - any suggestions?

Edit: open-vm-tools is installed

---

Edit: I've followed the guide mentioned in the comments (https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1027976), but no luck. I've also recreated the VM and done a clean install, same results.

I also tried using a regular Ubuntu VM to rule out any weirdness that elementary may be causing, but same results there as well.

In each case VMware Tools was installed. I also installed the open-vm-tools package.

I noticed sometimes when I test with a ping, I get results that the packet was filtered. This only happens with some hostnames, so it may not be related.

I also tried setting the network adapter type to VMXNET3 (per https://communities.vmware.com/thread/463728).

Comment: I am not clear. Fusion is for MAC OS (not Linux). So is your host MAC, or is it Linux?   Linux host should be using VMware Workstation for Linux

Comment: @John oops, typo... meant to say guest. Fixed.

Comment: Have you installed VMware Tools in the guest machine?  I use VMware Workstation for Windows. You would need to look up the Linux Support article at vmware.com for this information

Comment: @John yes, I’ve installed open-vm-tools

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, however there is a good VMware document for Fusion network performance that is worth reading:  https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1027976

Comment: @John Thanks for linking to the guide. I've gone through the whole guide, including a clean VM install, but no luck.